# How to import account form geth console to metamask (private blockchain)

Tags: metamask, console

I want to import accounts from geth console(private network) but I can't. I have UTC file when I create account with geth but when I open file and copy mac and paste to metamask (private key) account not match between geth and metamask.

I want to use account from geth to metamask.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:
1. visit the https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info
[image]
2. select the "Keystore / JSON File"
3. click the "SELECT WALLET FILE" and select the UTC--2018-09-08T03-31-16xxx-xxx file whic is located in your keystore folder.
4. If there is a "password" in your file, you will see a message "Your wallet is encrypted. Good! Please enter the password."
5. then, click the "Unlock" button
6. You may need to wait more than 10-30 seconds to be redirected to the next page and at the next page, you can get your private key
7. Open your metamask chrome extension
8. Change to the network
9. select "Import Account"
10. You can see a dropdown menu with "Private Key" or "JSON file"
[image]
11. Select "Private key"
12. Input your private key and it will create the same account address in metamask

Answer (score 3):

Copying the private key only (field *ciphertext* of the *UTC* file) will give two different public addresses (one in *geth* and another in *metamask*). To solve this problem import de *UTC* file (present in the node *keystore* folder) directly in *metamask*.

When importing a file in *metamask*, make sure that you have the extension (*metamask*) running in it's own tab, otherwise it will not import anything.

Opening the extension in a tab (select `Expand View` in the `...` menu):
[image]

Importing the file:
[image: Running MetaMask as tab]

More details here: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489351-Importing-Accounts

Comment: This worked for me. The key point was "make sure that you have the extension (metamask) running in it's own tab, otherwise it will not import anything."

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your account `$geth account new`
2. Remember the password you used.
3. Your private key will be in `~/.ethereum/keystore` or `~/.ethereum/keystore/rinkeby`
4. Open metamask, select the network and then select "Import Account"
5. Select Type "JSON File" (not "Private Key")
6. Go to `~/.ethereum/keystore` and select the private key (UTC-...)
7. Enter your password from where you created the account.
8. Voila! There's your new account.

Answer (score 0):

1. Private Network create then account create .
2. then database dir\keystore\UTC--2018-01-16T04-21-05.278923500Z--4c24e4e237441990d71cbd4d1d7cc13e77895ec8 file create .
3. File open and mac id : Example : "mac":"50e9fb34dda11dfe948d783ffb30e8c8670e501a57632bf146594e8aa79c99a7" copy just mac meanies 50e9fb34dda11dfe948d783ffb30e8c8670e501a57632bf146594e8aa79c99a7.
4. Then metamask import private key .

Then import account

Thanks

Comment: in console my addreess is 0xaa2190f6d036e91fb58f13939e10e865d440cd26 
but when import with mac my address show 0x8EF313D171FB45ae96Eb3972674aBdb0a5C53f51 Why is that?

Comment: yes then import metamask

Comment: 1.It is the same accounts?
2.am use miner.start but when import account to metamask don't have eth?

Comment: This tutorials view then your problem solve https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGIg8IBvrOk&index=5&list=PLwWaMqv4bjuxbmr7ePzOzSa4um6xZniVg

Comment: @ALOMGIRHOSSEN This is not correct the private key is encrypted with the password and is stored in "ciphertext" param.