# How to import quorum 7 node accounts to metamask

Tags: metamask, dapps, quorum

I am new to quorum 7node example 
I have created a DApp I want to send transaction using metamask
when I was using testrpc to connect with DApp i was able to see all 10 test accounts in metamask after loging in and  entering mnemonic
but now when I am using quorum I dont have any such mnemonic
i want to import node accounts to metamask how can i do that?
how to connect to custom rpc i mean i am sure what to enter in place of ? http:?:22000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the key of an account of quorum in metamask. Keys of all the accounts are available at https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/7nodes/keys.

In quorum 7nodes example only one account is imported at each of the seven nodes.
Node 1 is configured at port 22000 and account is imported using key 1. As only one account is imported into one node you will be able to see only one account after connecting to a specific node.

As you have configured quorum on your local machine you shall use http://127.0.0.1:22000 to connect to node` using metamask.

Comment: hey Thanks for helping for key1 address address":"ed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d and cciphertext":"4e77046ba3f699e744acb4a89c36a3ea1158a1bd90a076d36675f4c883864377" when i use this ciphertext as private key to import account in metamask it imported some account with this 0x86e961c7b74f760fe5DF0623f1bBD048c643F653 which is not same as address of geth node 1 account 1

Comment: @SurbhiAudichya, Welcome! Glad to help you. I don't know why ethereum account address is different from the address in a key store file. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: Those files are keystore wallet, the private key is encrypted, the encryption password an empty string (file passwords in parent directory). Unfortunatelly Metamask doesn't allow empty passwords and you can't open the file directly. You can open the keystore file from MEW and export the raw private key.

Comment: @Ismael hey can u please explain that in more detail. all i want is to import Quorum node1 account (0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d) to metamask so that i can make private transaction using metamask and DApp.

Answer (score 1):

For more detail information on how to import quorum coinbase accounts to metamask 
check "[How to import account form geth console to metamask (private blockchain)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45050/how-to-import-account-form-geth-console-to-metamask-private-blockchain)"