# Quorum 7node example when i try to import account1 of node1 using its key1 ciphertext i get wrong account address imported

Tags: metamask, quorum

I am trying to import account 1 of node1 of 7nodes quorum example using its key1 file which you can find here "https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/7nodes/keys".

my account 1 for node1 is address":"ed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d"

i used "ciphertext":"4e77046ba3f699e744acb4a89c36a3ea1158a1bd90a076d36675f4c883864377" to import account one in metamask so that i can use it while making transactions from DApp.

but i get some wrong account("0x86e961c7b74f760fe5DF0623f1bBD048c643F653") added in my metamask.

Please tell me how to add  7nodes example node 1 account address to metamask?

Comment: I found a solution here "https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45050/how-to-import-account-form-geth-console-to-metamask-private-blockchain"