# Unable to interact with DApp deployed on quorum

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, metamask, quorum

[image]I am unable to interact with contract using Dapp deployed on Quorum blockchain (using metamask).
I am following "https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains". I have successfully set up Quorum 7node blockchain 
then I created a simple set and get Dapp for the same contract given in the above link.
I have managed to import coinbase of each node to metamask. I have created 3 custom RPC http://127.0.0.1:22000, 22003 and 22006 and imported respective coinbase to metamask(following "[How to import account form geth console to metamask (private blockchain)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45050/how-to-import-account-form-geth-console-to-metamask-private-blockchain)").
I have created a simple app.js similar to truffle pet shop tutorial,

App.js file
[image]

I have deployed contract with privateFor tag in migration and for set function same as shown in truffle quorum 7node example.

But when I try to change the value of storage data from dapp, I am unable to change it (it reflect the same constant value).
whereas from geth node I am able to change value of storage data. Even from sampletx.js(using truffle exec sampletx.js) i am able to change storage data value .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can help you here Steps are

1. Vagrant up (only one time)
2. Vagrant ssh(one cmd panel)

You will get like **vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$**

After this go to cd quroum-example/7nodes/

3.on same cmd $./raft-start.sh
4.Run this command **vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/quorum-examples/7nodes$ geth attach qdata/dd1/geth**

Open new terminal and got to directory of **quroum-example** and and type vagrant ssh

5.open new geth instance here by using 3,4 steps above add geth instance but this time geth attach qdata/dd4/geth

6.this above is your build envirnoment for two geth instance.

7.In the tutorial "https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains" you will have directory like 
    [image]
 [image]

in the terminal of **geth attach qdata/dd1/geth** use this commands

```
=> var bytecode = "your smart Contract byte code"
 =>var simpleContract = eth.contract([{ "constant": true,"inputs": [],"name": "storedData","outputs": [{"name": "","type": "uint256"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"},{"inputs": [{"name": "initVal1","type": "uint256"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "constructor"},{"constant": false,"inputs": [{"name": "x","type": "uint256"}],"name": "set","outputs": [],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "function"},{"constant": true,"inputs": [],"name": "get","outputs": [{"name": "retVal","type": "uint256"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"}]) 

> simpleContract.new(20, {from:eth.accounts[0], data: bytecode, gas: 0x47b760,privateFor: ["ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="]})
```

And then check it with var test2 = attaching screeshots[image]

[image]

Comment: Do one thing deployed contract again and set the value of x again , or do one thing please remove "private for" and leave it empty here.Than please check it will work

Comment: actually, you are not using contact Address way, generally If i need to change the values I use contract address to call the smart contract abi. I asked you to remove because it will run for all network peers .